# React-slick with gatsby-plugin-image

Tags: graphql, gatsby, react-slick

I'm trying to use React-slick with gatsby-plugin images and I have the page setup like this.

```
import React from "react";
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import { GatsbyImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

const settings = {
  autoPlay: true,
  arrows: false,
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
};

const ImgSlide = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Slider {...settings}>
        <div>
          <GatsbyImage fluid={data.image1.childImageSharp.fluid} />
        </div>
        <div>
        <GatsbyImage fluid={data.image2.childImageSharp.fluid} />
        </div>
      </Slider>
    </div>
  );
};

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    image1: file(relativePath: { eq: "images/icon.png" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
    image2: file(relativePath: { eq: "images/icon.png" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default ImgSlide;
```

When i run Gatsby develop I get an error saying image1 is not defined. I really don't know what I'm missing here. I think it has something to do with how I'm trying to define image1 but I'm pretty sure I've used relativePath properly unless I'm not specifying the location properly.

I do have the same image specified twice that is just because I have not imported the photos in just yet I'm just testing to make it work.

gatsby-config setup is

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "Inkd Era",
    description: "Clothing and brand built for tattoo and tattoed culture",
  },
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-sass",
    "gatsby-plugin-image",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap",
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-manifest",
      options: {
        icon: "src/images/icon.png",
      },
    },
    "gatsby-transformer-remark",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp",
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-transformer-remark",
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-images",
            options: {
              maxWidth: 650,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "images",
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`,
      },
      __key: "images",
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "pages",
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages/`,
      },
      __key: "pages",
    },
    {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
    options: {
      name: `Inkd Era`,
      short_name: `Inkd era`,
      start_url: `/`,
      background_color: `#000`,
      theme_color: `#fafafa`,
      display: `standalone`,
      icon: `content/assets/gatsby-icon.png`,
    },
  },
  ],
};
```

Comment: start with testing queries in the playground

Comment: So when I run the query in graphiql running the same query structure does show the queried file. It has to be an issue with the image1: and image:2 but I don't know how else I'd declare these so I can reference them individually.

Comment: `console.log(data);` before return JSX?

Comment: Gatsby wont even build when I try to open in localhost it gives the error and wont let me pass it.

Comment: render some fake component or even a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure for the new `<GatsbyImage>` component when passing the image itself is using the `image` `prop`, not `fluid`. In addition, the query needs to fetch `gatsbyImageData`, not `fluid` as you can see in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-image):

```
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

function BlogPost({ data }) {
  const image = getImage(data.blogPost.avatar)
  return (
    <section>
      <h2>{data.blogPost.title}</h2>
      <GatsbyImage image={image} alt={data.blogPost.author} />
      <p>{data.blogPost.body}</p>
    </section>
  )
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    blogPost(id: { eq: $Id }) {
      title
      body
      author
      avatar {
        childImageSharp {
          gatsbyImageData(
            width: 200
            placeholder: BLURRED
            formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

In your scenario, you are mixing the [`gatsby-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/) approach, from Gatsby `v2` with the new `gatsby-plugin-image`, which stills in beta, but it's from the `v3`.

If you want to use the `<GatsbyImage>`, adapt the query and the component to the needs, otherwise, use the `gatsby-image` properly like:

```
import Img from `gatsby-image`

<Img fluid={data.image1.childImageSharp.fluid} />
```